# How to reference more than one controller in one view (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, models

I am building an application in CakePHP (I have been using this for a couple of months in a new job, and took over this project from the previous employee, so my understanding is limited).

This application has several database tables, the ones involved in this problem are Centres, Softwares and Categories.

To give you a brief, hat I need, is when a user visits the 'Centres' view, to be able to have a list of all of the software below, and tick which the centres have access to.

To view a list of software, my SoftwaresController uses the function:

```
public function view() {

$categories = $this->Software->Category->find ('list');
array_unshift ($categories, array('any' => 'Any'));
$this->set ('categories', $categories);
$this->Software->hasMany['Version']['limit'] = 1;
$this->Software->hasMany['Version']['fields'] = array('Version.id', 'Version.version_number', 'Version.created');
if ($this->request->is ('post') && $this->request->data) {
  $conditions = array();
  $filters = $this->request->data['Software'];
  if (!empty($filters['name'])) {
    $conditions['Software.name'] = $filters['name'];
  }
  if ($filters['category'] > 0) {
    $conditions['Category.id'] = $filters['category'];
  }
  $this->paginate = array(
      'conditions' => $conditions,
      'order' => array(
          'Software.latest_released' => 'desc',
          'Software.name' => 'asc'
      )
  );
  $this->set ('softwares', $this->paginate ());
  $this->set ('paging', false);
} else {
  $this->paginate = array(
      'order' => array(
          'Software.latest_released' => 'desc',
          'Software.name' => 'asc'
      )
  );
  $this->set ('paging', true);
  $this->set ('softwares', $this->paginate ());
}
// This allows the user software page to show.
}
```

In the CentresController function, in which I want to be able to also view the data (as extracted above), looks like this:

```
public function admin_view($id = null)
{

    /* Centres */
    $this->Centre->recursive = 0;
    $this->Centre->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Centre->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('This centre ID does not exist.'));
    }
    $centre = $this->Centre->read(null, $id);
    $this->request->data = $centre;
    $this->set('centre', $centre);
}
```

I have tried to combine the above two functions by adding the inside of view() into admin_view(). The view for admin_view() looks like this:

Assign Software Access

```
                      <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                              <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Version Number</th>
                                <th>Created</th>
                                <th>Modified</th>
                                <th>Released</th>
                                <th>Grant Permission</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                              <?php
                              $i = 0;
                              foreach ($software['Version'] as $version):
                                $class = null;
                                if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                                  $class = ' class="even"';
                                } else {
                                  $class = ' class="odd"';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
                                  <td><?php echo $version['version_number']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td>
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Time->format (Configure::read ('Format.time'), $version['created']);
                                    ?>&nbsp;
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Time->format (Configure::read ('Format.time'), $version['modified']);
                                    ?>&nbsp;
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Time->format (Configure::read ('Format.time'), $version['released']);
                                    ?>&nbsp;
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="actions" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Html->link (
                                        '<i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>&nbsp;Download',
                                        array(
                                            'controller' => 'versions',
                                            'action' => 'view',
                                            $version['id']
                                        ),
                                        array('escape' => false)
                                    );
                                    ?>&nbsp;

                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              <?php endforeach; ?>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                          <!-- /.table-responsive -->







                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 padding-right-0">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>&nbsp;Actions</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10">
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Form->button(
                                        '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Update',
                                        array(
                                            'type' => 'submit',
                                            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block',
                                            'escape' => false
                                        )
                                    );
                                    echo $this->Form->end();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10 -->
                                <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" href="#modal-dialog"
                                       data-toggle="modal"
                                       data-target="#modal-dialog"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10 -->
                                <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10">
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Html->link(
                                        "<span class='fa fa-times'></span>&nbsp;Cancel",
                                        array(
                                            'action' => 'index'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'escape' => false,
                                            'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block'
                                        )
                                    );
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-sm-4 padding-bottom-10 -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on null
>   File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/licensemanagementsite/app/Controller/CentresController.php
>   Line: 87

I have also included at the top of the CentresController and the Centres model:
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller', 'SoftwaresController');

Any assistance you can give me would be really appreciated. No one in my office knows anything about CakePHP (including me, I guess!).

Thanks!

Comment: what is there in line 87 of CentresController.php

Comment: Use requestAction method inside the view. Or in controller if you want at that place.
$this->requestAction('controller/action);
echo $this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'featured'),
    array('named' => array('limit' => 3))
);

echo $this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('pass' => array(5))

Comment: line 87: > $categories = $this->Software->Category->find ('list');

Answer (score 0):

In CakePhp the view file can only takes output from its associative controller. You can not call controllers in view file. Also two controllers can not be used together i.e. if you want to use a function of A controller into B controller then it is not possible directly or may be not a good practice.

If you want to use some common functionality between two controllers, then you should use "COMPONENTS". read [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) here to create components.
After creating the function into component, you can use that function in any controller by just including the component in it. Using component you can set the result of the component to a variable and then that variable can be used in the associative view file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving what you want.
Keeping in mind that one model is linked with one table, the first you should be aware is that one controller does not need to be associated only with one model. For that you use the public variable "uses" in this case in your Centres controller we would be having something like:

```
<?php
class CentresController extends AppController
{
  public uses = array(Centre, Software);

  public function action1()
  {...}
  ...
}
```

Then you should move the logic that fetches the data to your model, and fetch the data from the controller. Let's say you want the software of a particular category. Then in Software model you would create a function like:

```
public function fetchSoftwareType($type)
{
  return $this->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(category=>$type)));
}
```

(for more on this have a look at [Models/Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) -this link is for version 2.X, search in yours-)
Then from your Centres controller you would be getting your software depending on category by simply calling `$this->Software->fetchSoftwareType($filters['category'])`.
Analogally you can retrieve similar data calling from this same controller to the corresponding method in Centre model for example `$this->Centre->fetchCentreData($whatever)`.

```
<?php
class CentresController extends AppController
{
  public uses = array(Centre, Software);

  public function view()
  {
    $softData = $this->Software->fetchSoftwareType($filters['category']);
    $centreData = $this->Centre->fetchCentreData($whatever);
    //.... process the data
    //$resultForView = $this->processData($softData, $centreData);
    //....
    $this->set('centre', $resultForView);
  }
  ...
}
```

The point is, you can get the data you need from as many models as are set in the `uses` variable, the process it and set it for the view to display it.